# Finding fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need help with finding the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ of the function $f(t) = \sin(\omega t)$ with a period of $T$. Which coefficients are non-zero?

---

[image: I suppose that this is needed to be used to find them:]

---

I would be very thankful with every help I could get, I am very new to this area.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: @C-RAM I think that because sin is odd, it doesn't have an $a_n$ and that the integration only is for $b_n$ but i am not sure when it is this way. Or if i should express it as a complex function and then integrate? I don't know how to work with a period T either. I am new and very confused how to solve these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

A periodic function $f(t) $with period $T$ can be written as:
$$ f\left(t\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}\left(n\right)e^{\frac{2\pi j\cdot n}{T}t} $$ where $$\hat{f}(n) =\frac{1}{T}\int\limits _{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}f\left(x\right)e^{-\frac{2\pi nx}{T}}dx $$

The fourier series is unique to each function.

Because of that and Euler's formula we can use the fact that $$ \sin\left(\omega_{0}t\right)=\frac{1}{2j}\left(e^{j\omega_{0}t}-e^{-j\omega_{0}t}\right) $$
Which means:
$$ \sin\left(\omega_{0}t\right)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}t\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}\left(n\right)e^{\frac{2\pi}{T}jnt}:\hat{f}\left(n\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2j} & n=1\\
-\frac{1}{2j} & n=-1\\
0 & else
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Thank you for the help! I just have one last question, how did you get to the final conclusion for f_n ? I also assume that the j stands for the complex number i.

Comment: yes it is,in engineering it is more commonly used at least.
The Fourier series for a periodic function is unique, therefore there is only 1 function $\hat{f}(n)$ that fits.
And I used Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x) $ to find that $\sin \left(x\right)=\frac{e^{jx}-e^{-jx}}{\:2j} $
This is a sum of coefficients that look like exponents(just like the ones we are looking in the fourier series)
So because we know this one such represantation and it is unique, this is the Fourier series.